# For-loop in R, replacing nth and nth+1

Tags: r, for-loop

I need some help with a for-loop I've been working with. I don't know if what I have done is even possible, but I hope you can help me make it work.

Initially, I have a list of 100 elements, which are all FALSE. 
I want to pass through 100 variables to change the elements (FALSE/TRUE).
Step 1 should change every element to TRUE,
Step 2 changes every second element(starting at 2); if FALSE to TRUE and if TRUE to FALSE,
Step 3 changes every third element, and so on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
X = rep(FALSE,100)

for (i in X) {
 if (i == X[1]) {
 X[X%%1==0] == TRUE
 } else {
   i = i+1
   k = X[X%%i==0]
   for (i in k) {
    if (k == TRUE) {
    replace(X, k, FALSE)
  } else {
    replace(X, k, TRUE)
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Finally I want the outcome to sum all the elements that are TRUE, but I don't know how to put that in the loop.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, by Nr I mean step (as guessed by Hack-R below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = rep(FALSE,100)

for (i in 1:length(X)) { 
  # Reverse the value of every element, 
  # then every 2nd starting with 2, 
  # then every 3rd element starting with 3, 
  # etc, through every 100th element starting with 100
  for(j in 1:100){
  if(i %in% seq(j,length(X),j)){ 
    X[i] <- ifelse(X[i]==FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)  
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I see now that my first step is missing! The code is supposed to start with:
    for (i in X) {    
Is it possible to make a loop going through all the 100 steps?

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been very helpful. The problem is that I want to apply 100 steps, not only three. Meaning I want to reverse the value of every nth element up to 100. Is it possible to make the rule general? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @C.Bailey Now I understand. I've updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: @C.Bailey By the way, you can click the green checkmark to let future readers know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
for (i in 1:100) X[seq(i, 100, i)]=!X[seq(i, 100, i)]

which(X)
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Answer (score 0):

No outer loop should be necessary:

```
X<- rep(FALSE,100)
for(n in 1:length(X))
{   ix<- n*(1:(length(X)/n))
    X[ix]<- !X[ix]
}

 which(X)
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```